# Compiler optimization: CIL assembly

Tags: .net, optimization, compiler-construction, bytecode, cil

I'm currently writing some kind of optimizing compiler.

I'd like to know if there are any optimizations that can be implemented on CIL (or java bytecode) level?

PS i've met ProGuard project http://proguard.sourceforge.net/ that implements lots of optimizations, but it manipulates with java bytecode. Is there a similiar project for .net?

Comment: Take a look at projects for Mono.Cecil http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil#Projects

Comment: I have read about their plans, just wanted to invite them to look at the results of my work, when there will be something to show.
They have that project on the agenda for one year, but I saw no meaningful resuls.

Comment: Of course there are possibilities. You can get rid of unnecessary heap allocations, you can remove virtual calls where it is possible, do the high level algorithmic optimisations. But it is really hard - you'd need a full-blown global static analysis in order to perform these optimisations.